# R draw a circle arround each point in scatterplot

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have a scatterplot in a rectangle 10 by 10 (says) and I want to draw a circle with radius = 3 around each point in this scatterplot.
Do you have any idea about it ?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want both scatter points and circles of a given size (relative to the x-axis coordinates or actual size in inches/cm) I suggest you use the `symbols()` function

```
x <- 10*runif(4)
y <- 10*runif(4)
symbols(x, y, circles=rep(3, length(x)), inches=FALSE,
        xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10))
points(x, y, pch=19)
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome! Just note that if you resize the figure, the circles will not turn into ellipses but just rescale according to the x-axis.

Answer (score 3):

```
plot(10*runif(10),10*runif(10),cex=10)
```